# Array with 91 items, trying to reduce redundancy

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with 91 items, and I don't want to constantly use `$data[1]`, `$data[2]`, etc. and it seems redundant to make 91 separate variables just to make it easier to remember what each data item does.

Does anyone know how I can give each of these items a name easier? Or am I just stuck with manually naming each one...

```
array(91) { [0]=> string(6) "537146" [1]=> string(4) "1212" [2]=> string(7) "7902400" [3]=> string(6) "670563" [4]=> string(2) "69" [5]=> string(6) "674789" [6]=> string(6) "576650" [7]=> string(2) "68" [8]=> string(6) "628147" [9]=> string(6) "690316" [10]=> string(2) "71" [11]=> string(6) "831597" [12]=> string(6) "746547" [13]=> string(2) "70" [14]=> string(6) "776478" [15]=> string(6) "832324" [16]=> string(2) "65" [17]=> string(6) "455705" [18]=> string(6) "710640" [19]=> string(2) "47" [20]=> string(5) "76682" [21]=> string(6) "722402" [22]=> string(2) "66" [23]=> string(6) "512396" [24]=> string(6) "863938" [25]=> string(2) "51" [26]=> string(6) "123086" [27]=> string(6) "143396" [28]=> string(2) "80" [29]=> string(7) "2163323" [30]=> string(6) "435239" [31]=> string(2) "67" [32]=> string(6) "560102" [33]=> string(7) "1078055" [34]=> string(2) "47" [35]=> string(5) "80051" [36]=> string(6) "601043" [37]=> string(2) "51" [38]=> string(6) "114870" [39]=> string(6) "715865" [40]=> string(2) "51" [41]=> string(6) "112269" [42]=> string(6) "403800" [43]=> string(2) "57" [44]=> string(6) "219098" [45]=> string(6) "697401" [46]=> string(2) "52" [47]=> string(6) "124179" [48]=> string(6) "599311" [49]=> string(2) "38" [50]=> string(5) "32070" [51]=> string(6) "769359" [52]=> string(2) "44" [53]=> string(5) "59335" [54]=> string(6) "472791" [55]=> string(2) "53" [56]=> string(6) "138904" [57]=> string(6) "591165" [58]=> string(2) "55" [59]=> string(6) "172795" [60]=> string(6) "500981" [61]=> string(2) "33" [62]=> string(5) "19433" [63]=> string(6) "650383" [64]=> string(2) "23" [65]=> string(4) "6979" [66]=> string(6) "552008" [67]=> string(2) "29" [68]=> string(5) "12185" [69]=> string(6) "692439" [70]=> string(2) "25" [71]=> string(4) "7927" [72]=> string(2) "-1" [73]=> string(2) "-1" [74]=> string(2) "-1" [75]=> string(2) "-1" [76]=> string(6) "483773" [77]=> string(1) "6" [78]=> string(6) "362146" [79]=> string(1) "3" [80]=> string(6) "347664" [81]=> string(1) "3" [82]=> string(2) "-1" [83]=> string(2) "-1" [84]=> string(2) "-1" [85]=> string(2) "-1" [86]=> string(2) "-1" [87]=> string(2) "-1" [88]=> string(2) "-1" [89]=> string(2) "-1" [90]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Why not just keep them inside array only, and refer to those values using a single variable array ? That is the whole purpose of using lists (arrays)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I thought about doing that, but then I have to remember what each one does. It can become confusing. I didn't make the array like that btw... It's from an API and I have no idea why they didn't add keys to it

Comment: And, how would you name those 91 variables ? If you are going to name them as `var_1`, `var_2` and so on.. Then, what difference would it make, instead of using `$data[1]` and so on..

Comment: You know that arrays can have string indexes e.g. -> `[ "size" => 12, "type" => 6]`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a try like this way to create multiple variables for your each and every element of array using `foreach()`.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    ${"var_$key"}  = $value;
}

echo "variable no 1 is = $var_1, variable no 50 is = $var_50, and variable no 90 is = $var_90";
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/DXvVp